# ¿Como puedo recorrer un DataGrid y obtener los valores de la ceda? c# WPF

Tags: c#, lista, wpf, foreach, datagrid

quiero recorrer cada fila del DataGrid y obtener los valores de cada celda.

mi DataGrid tiene por nombre: DGDLISTA

Al DataGrid lo cargo de la siguiente manera

```
 String CADENA = "select * from mitabla";
                OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(CADENA, connection);
                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();
                if (reader.HasRows != false)
                {
                    DGDLISTA.ItemsSource = reader.Cast<Object>();
                    DGDLISTA.Items.Refresh();
                  //  reader.Close();
                }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y el problema es?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque me falta información, te paso un ejemplo funcional para ve si te sirve.

```
       dg_data.SelectAllCells();
        foreach( DataGridCellInfo d in dg_data.SelectedCells)
        {
            if (dg_data.Columns[0]==d.Column)//evita repetidos ya que devuelve la fila
              Console.WriteLine(d.Item.ToString());//d.Item usando binding 
   devuelve el itemsource 
          }
```